# Class and function structure (Java)

Tags: java, oop

I am creating an employee management system as a project for my CV and I am relatively new to structuring code in different classes and files in java projects and I was just wondering if someone just answer a couple of questions :).

So just as an overview of the project: I am using Java as the code and then SQL for a database using JDBC as the driver. It will have 2 parts, an HR part and a Non HR part. These will both be separate classes and will have their own functions, some of the basic functionality of these will be:

**HR**

- Search for employees
- Add/Remove employees
- Accept/Decline holiday requests
- Give pay rise
- Promote Employee
- Accept/Decline overtime hours

**Non HR**

- Change name
- Change gender
- Change address
- Change bank details
- Request/withdraw holidays
- Request a meeting

As I am using a database I have a lot of functions which are sort of generic functions, or functions containing data structures that are used in both sides of the program and need to be shared between the two.

Would the best way to be to have a parent class 'Person' for example, which has these functions in so it can be accessed by them all, or is there a different and better way to go about it?

**Also** if I have a function which is a one off and not specifically relevant to either class, where should it be written?

Cheers in advance guys :)

Comment: If the *member attributes* you are creating are going to be shared *publicly* among other classes or by different methods you can create one template class for that case. If the complexity is where you need to manipulate more than one attribute or adding more function definitions to your class it maybe good to look into *multiple inheritance*. Create the functions required separately from your main, so yes, separate .java files.

Comment: Cool, cheers dude. Just a quick follow up to that, if I have a function which is a one off and not specifically relevant to either class, where should it be written? @FishingCode

Comment: If it is one off function, you can place that anywhere it makes sense to within the main file as well or the file that already has the defined attributes and methods.

Comment: Last follow up question, I promise...XD. I want to integrate a UI which will be in the console, where should these functions go? The gist of it is that I will have the main program and then these functions will be used for taking input and displaying information

Comment: It looks like you are asking this question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a abstract class named Employee.java and set fundamental methods and force both HR and Non-HR employees to take on fundamental fields like employee Id’s, Hire Date, Pay Rates, etc. You can make your Non-HR and HR Employee classes ‘extend’ the Employee class and then define constructors in each.

In each constructor define each variable to the class and call set Methods for each field, in the method it should check for conditions such as
- name > 0 || name != null
- payRate > 0 
- etc

Hope this helps.

- Object Inheritance, Polymorphism

Comment: Cool, cheers dude. Just a quick follow up to that, if I have a function which is a one off and not specifically relevant to either class, where should it be written?